# Subrequest is mandatory in case of specific rules?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables.

```
BUG (BugId, BugStatus)
LINK (LinkId, LinkBugId, LinkTestId)
TEST (TestId, TestName, TestStatus)
```

I need to find all tests with the status `F` or `B` AND linked with 0 bug OR linked with Bug in status `C` or `CR`. But if there is 2 bugs linked to the test, one is `C`, the other one is `O` then the record should not be retreived. If both are `C` or `CR`, then record should be retreived.

I started to write the below request, however I'm not sure if using a subrequest if the good way to do.

```
SELECT TEST.TestId
FROM TEST INNER JOIN LINK ON TEST.TestId = LINK.LinkTestID
INNER JOIN BUG ON LINK.TestBugId = BUG.BugId
WHERE TEST.TestStatus IN ('F', 'B')    
AND TEST.TestId NOT IN (
    SELECT TEST.TestId
    FROM TEST INNER JOIN LINK ON TEST.TestId = LINK.LinkTestID
    INNER JOIN BUG ON LINK.TestBugId = BUG.BugId
    WHERE TEST.TestStatus IN ('F', 'B')
    AND BUG.BugStatus NOT IN ('C', 'CR') // moreover this filter is not sufficient to match with rules
)
ORDER BY TEST.TestId
```

Can you please help me?

Many thanks in advance

**Update 1**

[image]

In this example, records retrieved should be 5, 6, 7 and 10.

Comment: You dont want to retrive test information if it linked to two bugs with status 'C' and 'O'?

Comment: No, it should not be present

Comment: @Royce . . . Your description is incomplete.  What if there are three bugs, C, CR, and O.  Or two and they are C and U?

Comment: Then record should not be retreive. It should be retreive only if all linked bugs are C and/or CR (or 0 bug linked).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `having` clause with `group by` as follows(You need to use `LEFT JOIN` for 0 bug condition):

```
SELECT TEST.TestId
  FROM TEST 
  LEFT JOIN LINK ON TEST.TestId = LINK.LinkTestID
  LEFT JOIN BUG ON LINK.TestBugId = BUG.BugId and BUG.BugStatus IN ('C', 'CR') 
 WHERE TEST.TestStatus IN ('F', 'B')     
 GROUP BY TEST.TestId
HAVING count(case when TEST.TestStatus = 'B' then 1 end) > 0 
    or count(distinct BUG.BugStatus) = 2
ORDER BY TEST.TestId
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but 2 was an example, it can be 0 or 2 or 10 or etc ... bug linked

Comment: Yes, but you want the 0 bugs linked or bugs with the status only in `C` and `CR`. Try this code.

Comment: Yes of course I will. Can you explain me quickly this line `count(distinct case when BUG.BugStatus IN ('C', 'CR') then 1 end) = 2 ` ?

Comment: It will check that both C and CR should be linked to test. it is in having clause so it works on the GROUP (testid)

Comment: I have updated the answer -- added one more condition in having. Please check.

Comment: Thank you but why `=2` ? It can be 3, 4, 5, ... bugs linked.

Comment: But you want to get only those tests which have C or CR. so it is 2

Comment: Yes correct, sorry ... Thank you, I will try and get back to give you feedback !

Comment: Unfortunately this request retreive 0 record

Comment: You can provide the sample data and expected output then.It is quite difficult to understand what is exact data and how to manipulate it

Comment: Of course, I added an Excel table with data example. I hope it will help to understand

Comment: Why you have written that 5 should be in the result? it is linked to only one bug, with status = 'C'

Comment: Because Test is 'B'. Yes it can be linked to one bug, or two, or three or four, or ... not necessarily 0 or 2.

Comment: Can I write `count(case when TEST.TestStatus = 'B' or TEST.TestStatus = 'F' then 1 end) > 0` to include status `F`. Moreover, why did you remove `or count(BugId) = 0` ?

Comment: Based on your requirement. You don't need to write condition for `F` as in case of `F`, Query will go and check that C and CR both bugs are linked to test

Comment: Now the request retreive records but too many. Like TestId 2. One bug is CR but the other one is O. Then TestId 2 should not be retrieved.

Comment: TestId 2 can not be in the result as it must be failing both the conditions in the HAVING clause

Comment: I checked again and same case as TestId 2 happens. One bug is C, another is O and record is present in the list. Both are linked to TestId 2.